# How do I get the search menu to appear in the Xpages perspective in Domino Designer

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

In Domino Designer 9, I have a Search menu at the top when I have the Domino Designer perspective open.  When I switch to XPages, it disappears.  I like the Xpages perspective as it gives easy access to the Faces Config file, but I also like having the search menu available.  Is there a way to have both of these in one perspective?  I am not averse to creating a custom perspective if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution is to modify your application navigator for your Domino Designer perspective to include faces-config (in Preferences):

[image]

Comment: Quick and simple.  Thanks.  I can even ditch some stuff I never use.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something may have got corrupt with the install, because it's showing for me. It might be worth running the installer again, to see if that resolves the problem.

Alternatively, it may not have been set as a command on the XPages perspective. If you go to Window > Customize Perspective..., then on the Commands tab, you can tick "Search"

[image: Customize Perspective]

Comment: I can't face a reinstall at the moment as I have just gone through fix packs galore.  I'll look at a vanilla install on a vm when I get a chance.  I think my client has been constantly patched from about 8.5 so, would be interesting to see if it can be recreated.

Comment: A couple of useful links for exporting many preferences: http://www.intec.co.uk/quick-setup-restore-of-domino-designer/ and http://www.intec.co.uk/restoring-domino-designer-including-working-sets/. I've found working sets unreliable though. If the Workspace folder is left intact, it shouldn't be necessary. DDE will also try to reinstall plugins when it starts up again. But plugins can always be stored in a Widget Catalog under a category that's also ticked in your preferences. Then they will be re-installed automatically too.